# Intelllij IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 groovy code completion does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, code-completion

I can create a Groovy project and even run it.  But when I type main or print there are no auto-complete / code completion suggestions at all.  I have groovy-2.4.1 in the external library folder along with Java 1.8.  I find Intellij frustrating and non-intuitive to use.

In a groovy script main does show correct code completion but when I click enter it puts "main()" without the String[] args that I can see in the suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have created a Groovy class where code has to be embedded into a class to be executable and where only class member declarations are expected (e.g. functions, fields). Select to create a Groovy script (or just delete class declaration) to be able to write executable code in top level file. See also [Scripts versus classes](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_scripts_versus_classes).

Comment: so are you saying there is no code completion for a .groovy class?  that makes no sense, mostly I write java and code completion works perfectly for .java classes.

Comment: I'm saying the the `main` is not a valid member declaration for the class. I have the completion in Groovy class: https://i.imgur.com/mw9JsjJ.png If you do not see a completion at all try File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart, disable 3rd plugins if you have any.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem when I was in a rush and forgot to add a method in which to write the code. Just type '`psvm` + Enter' inside the class. This will create a main method in which code completion will work. Also, you can remove the `public` keyword as classes and methods in Groovy are by default public.

Comment: I didn't use public keyword but thanks for the reminder about default access level

Comment: pvsm+enter writes:  @Override
    void setMetaClass(MetaClass metaClass) {
        super.setMetaClass(metaClass)
    }

Comment: You should use that key combination inside the actual class. For me it works and creates the main method. I don't know why it overrides the `setMetaClass` method for you. Try using TAB instead of Enter. If that shortcut doesn't work either, then just add :

`static void main(String[] args) {
        
 }`